# VHDL program for A xor b xor c

Tags: vhdl, xor

I have to write a VHDL program in XILINX for the following expression:

```
Z = A xor B xor C.
```

This is one of my first VHDL programs so I'm not comfortable with the syntax. Kindly help me with the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start is the [Wikipedia VHDL page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl), and the first one under [Design examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl#Design_examples) is very similar to what you request, you just have to replace `O <= I1 and I2;` with `Z <= A xor B xor C;` and modify the interface accordingly.

To get a simulator that can compile and simulate VHDL, you can use ModelSim-Altera Starter Edition, which is free.  You can get it at [ModelSim-Altera Edition Software](http://www.altera.com/products/software/quartus-ii/modelsim/qts-modelsim-index.html).

For additional VHDL reading, look at [Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl#Further_reading).  Note that VHDL is **not** a programming language, but a Hardware **Description** Language (HDL), and thereby different from ordinary programming languages.  In order to get a good VHDL experience I suggest that you dig into some of the resources to learn the basic concepts.